# have hyperlink behave link display:block but also have image on same line?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following... http://jsfiddle.net/tLUkV/ I'd like my hyperlink to spread on till end of line like `display: block;` but I want the image on the same line like `display: in-line;` Is there a way to achieve a hybrid and get what I want?

EDIT: Just to clarify..

I'd like the image to the left and the hyperlink text right after it but the hyperlink itself span the entire line

Comment: so you want the image all the way to the left and hyperlink all the way to the right and on same line?

Comment: not all the way to the right. I'd like the image to the left and the hyperlink text right after it but the hyperlink itself span the entire line

Answer (score 1):

I would just set the link like a block and use the image as a background image for the link. Some left padding and it should appear exactly as you want it to.

```
a:link{
    display: block;
    background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 30px;        /* whatever you need */
    line-height: 30px;         /* whatever you need */
}
```

**Edit:** changed `height` to `line-height` to have the text center vertically

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a requirement for the link to extend all the way to the right, then the following would work:

```
img
{
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
}
a
{
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/AyZ22/5/

Usually you would accomplish something like this with `display: inline-block` though.

Answer (score 0):

using the image as a background would be the usual way to "iconify" links

here's a sample **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWEDu/4/)**

(icon was actually bigger than your dimensions so fiddled to suit) you then just give the links a different class name to change their background